# jQuery Masonry making Ajax call removes class masonry-brick

Tags: ajax, jquery-masonry

I'm using the jQuery plugin Masonry and I'm having an issue that happens when I make an ajax call to another page to load in images for a gallery. The ajax call works and the images load in but when the call is made, something happens that removes one of the classes that Masonry appends too one of my divs.

Here is how my html looks on the first page. Everything is fine here and shows the class masonry-brick, which I need to render out the appropriate css to make everything look nice and it also renders out the inline css.

```
  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/15/original/berkshire_25585_walnut_famousdaves03.jpg?1330115640" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
    **<div class="item masonry-brick" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">**<img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/15/gallery/berkshire_25585_walnut_famousdaves03.jpg?1330115640" title="Berkshire" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Berkshire</h3>
      <p>HDP &ndash; High Definition Porcelain</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

When I click on the link to make the ajax call, the images load in fine and it works on all the links but the class masonry-brick is removed and the images lose their css.

```
  jQuery("#project-galleries-navigation li.load-category a").on("click", function(){      
     var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");
            jQuery("#gallery").fadeOut(300).remove("img").load(href).fadeIn(2300);      
        return false;           
  });
```

This is the code i'm using for masonry.

```
var $container = jQuery('#copy-wrapper-gallery');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    isAnimated: true            
  });
});
```

This is what ends up happening to my html when the page loads in the new data. The class masonry-brick is no longer present and the inline css disappears as well.

```
  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/7/original/ashton_23931_smokey_beige_.jpg?1330114250" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
   **<div class="item">**<img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/7/gallery/ashton_23931_smokey_beige_.jpg?1330114250" title="Ashton" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Ashton</h3>
      <p>Porcelain</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

Has anyone had this problem or knows a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by modifying this jquery and putting in a callback function for it.

```
            jQuery("#gallery").fadeOut(300).remove("img").load(href, function(){
                    jQuery("#gallery").masonry("reload");
                }).fadeIn(2300);    
                e.preventDefault();                     
      });
```